# Error while upgrading Asterisk to 14 - PJSIP undeclared

Tags: makefile, debian, asterisk

I am trying to upgrade asterisk 11 to 14 on Debian (8.7) and I got the following error when I do make install.

The error is as below

```
res_pjsip_transport_management.c: In function ‘monitored_transport_state_callback’:
res_pjsip_transport_management.c:190:8: error: ‘PJSIP_TP_STATE_SHUTDOWN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   case PJSIP_TP_STATE_SHUTDOWN:
        ^
res_pjsip_transport_management.c:190:8: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/root/asterisk-14.3.0/Makefile.rules:149: recipe for target 'res_pjsip_transport_management.o' failed
make[1]: *** [res_pjsip_transport_management.o] Error 1
Makefile:401: recipe for target 'res' failed
make: *** [res] Error 2
```

The commands I used are as follow

```
tar -zxvf asterisk-14-current.tar.gz
/etc/init.d/asterisk stop
cd asterisk-14.3.0/
./configure
rm -f /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/*
make install
```

I tried some solutions from the internet and it didn't fix....

Comment: did you re-build/upgrade pjsip against the new install?

Comment: Nope, I didn't.

Comment: try that then reload the pjsip modules or restart the pbx and let me know if that fixes it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the pjsip versions do not match (could be that there is more then one version installed) so you want to remove all previous/existing versions of PJSip. If you do not know what packages belong to pjsip you can search them via:

```
apt-cache search pjsip
```

or

```
dpkg -l | grep pj
```

And once you know which package to remove do

```
apt-get --purge remove <package name>
```

You then want to download the latest version of pjsip (current 2.6 according to Asterisk website)

```
wget wget http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.6/pjproject-2.6.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf pjproject-2.6.tar.bz2
```

You want to place the pjproject in /usr/local.

```
cp -R pjproject-2.6 /usr/local/
```

Once this is done you have to build/compile/install the pjproject and

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared CFLAGS='-O2 -DNDEBUG' //Various options (enable/disable) can be put in here. Please refer to manual 
make dep
make
make install
ldconfig
```

Verify that pjproject has been installed in the target location

```
ldconfig -p | grep pj
```

Once this has been done you can now go to you Asterisk folder and issue

```
./configure
```

and proceed with installation further :)

Answer (score 1):

pjsip version not match.

Never tried 14*(it is not LTS), for 13.* such error mean you have more then one pjsip or pjsip is not 2.4.

Before rebuilding pjsip do check

```
yum remove -y pjsip
rm -f `find / -name *pjsip*`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, Asterisk 13 source code came with a built-in pjproject, but 14 will look for an installed pjproject on the system.

Make sure you have it installed (including the -dev or -devel packages, which contains the headers), than try to reconfigure asterisk source.

```
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make menuconfig
```